# Add multiple columns with mutate using column-based conditions, without using explicit column name + POSIX

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe of data: 1 column is POSIX, the rest is data.

I need to remove selectively some data from a group of columns and add these "new" columns to the original dataframe.

I can "easily" do it in base R (I am an old-style user). I'd like to do it more compactly with `mutate_at` or with other function... although I am having several issues.

A solution homemade with base R could be

```r
df <- data.frame("date" = seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct(format(Sys.time(),"%F %T"),tz="UTC"),length.out=20,by="min"), "a.1" = rnorm(20,0,3), "a.2" = rnorm(20,1,2), "b.1"= rnorm(20,1,4), "b.2"= rnorm(20,3,4))

df1 <- lapply(df[,grep("^a",names(df))], function(x) replace(x, which(x > 0 & x < 0.2), NA))
df1 <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(df1), nrow = nrow(df), byrow = F)) ## convert to data.frame
names(df1) <- grep("^a",names(df),value=T) ## rename columns
df1 <- cbind.data.frame("date"=df$date, df1) ## add date
```

Can anyone help me in setting up something working with dplyr + transmute?

So far I come up with something like:

```r
df %>%
    select(starts_with("a.")) %>%
    transmute(
        case_when(
            .>0.2 ~ NA,
            )
    ) %>%
    cbind.data.frame(df)
```

But I am quite stuck, since I can't combine `transmute` with `case_when`: all examples that I found use explicitly the column names in `case_when`, but I can't, since I won't know the names of the column in advance. I will only know the initial of the columns that I need to transmute.

Thanks,
 Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `transmute_at` if the intention is to return only those columns specified in the `vars`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   transmute_at(vars(starts_with('a')), ~ case_when(. > 0.2~ NA_real_, TRUE~ .)) %>%
   bind_cols(df %>% select(date), .)
```

If we need all the columns to return, but only change the columns of interest in `vars`, then we need `mutate_at` instead of `transmute_at`

```
df %>% 
   mutate_at(vars(starts_with('a')), ~ case_when(. > 0.2~ NA_real_, TRUE~ .)) %>%
   select(date, starts_with('a')) # only need if we are selecting a subset of columns
```

Comment: Thanks akrun! It works and it is simple. Actually I changed slightly since the solution using ```mutate_at``` (I don't know why) it gives the same results as the one with ```transmute_at```. In the end I came up with this 
```df %>% 
    transmute_at(vars(starts_with('a')), ~ case_when(. > 0.2~ NA_real_, TRUE~ .)) %>%
    rename_at(vars(starts_with('a')),function(x) paste0(x,".clean")) %>%
    bind_cols(df, .)```

And in this case I am keeping all columns.